# magento after login it shows login only

Tags: magento-1.9

I restrict magento default redirection after login by this method

```
System > Config > Customer 
> Custumer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > NO
```

It works fine but my problem is it redirect to previous page but top link still showing login only.

Once i reload my browser it change into logout

Comment: Are you using a customized theme ? is full page cache on ?

Comment: yes i am customize my own theme but i don't have any full page cache extension

Comment: is it an ajax login ?

Comment: No ajax magento default login page. If i set yes as above option it redirect to my account and login change into logout

Comment: do you have cache enabled ?

Comment: cache is disabled only